# CSS layout positioning boxes

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to achieve this layout without dividing it into 3 independent rows?

Like for example to be 1 row with multiple columns and to be like in the codepen?

https://codepen.io/konstantin97/pen/OJxXVLE

```css
.box-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -15px;
}

.box-col {
  padding: 15px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box-row">
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-row">
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-row">
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your current solution unacceptable?

Comment: Because it will be more responsive when there is on 1 row if i use flex-wrap: wrap for example. So if i want on tablet i can drop them to be 2 on a row and if it is like this i can't.

Answer (score 0):

additional question , do you need the distance between the blocks to be equal ? If not you can try and inline styling to the first 2 blocks adding margin-left on the first block and margin-right to the second block . All bocks should also have style="display:inline-block" to ensure they align horizontally. will try and also provide a code example shortly !

Comment: Yes, i need them to be equal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I added `flex-wrap: wrap`. See if that meets your "responsive" needs:

```css
.box-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;              /* added */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -15px;
}

.box-col {
  padding: 15px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box-row">
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-row">
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-row">
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-col">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, right now if second row drop because of flex-wrap: wrap; there will be 2 items and then 1 and then the other row starts. Try to make the box with width: 150px; and see what happens and this is what im trying to avoid.